# java,eclipse - eclipse brings hs_err_pid file everytime?

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, java-8

eclipse close every time and bring   hs_err_pid  file
[hs_err_pid image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1OIj.png)

However I'm using the latest version of java

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The hs_err_pid file is created when java crashes because of a fatal error. You should read the message in the file, or add the content to your question.